# how to get multiple records from static form in rails for database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The main form

```
<%=  p.fields_for :prd_province_vise_deliveries  do |j| %>

   <%= render(:partial => 'prd_province_vise_delivery_field', :locals => {:k => j})%>
<% end %>
```

and this is my prd_province_vise_delivery_field partial

```
       <div>
         <table class="table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th> Province name </th>
              <th> Delivery rate (Rs)</th>
              <th> Delivery period(Days) </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>   
            <tr>
              <td><%= k.label :province_name , 'Western'%></td>
              <td><%= k.text_field(:delivery_rate, {placeholder: '0', class: 'form-control input_border input_field_text_align_right'})%> </td>
              <td> <%= k.text_field(:delivery_period, {placeholder: '0', class: 'form-control input_border input_field_text_align_right'})%></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><%= k.label :province_name , 'Southern'%> </td>
              <td><%= k.text_field(:delivery_rate, {placeholder: '0', class: 'form-control input_border input_field_text_align_right'})%> </td>
              <td> <%= k.text_field(:delivery_period, {placeholder: '0', class: 'form-control input_border input_field_text_align_right'})%></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><%= k.label :province_name , 'Nothern'%> </td>
              <td><%= k.text_field(:delivery_rate, {placeholder: '0', class: 'form-control input_border input_field_text_align_right'})%> </td>
              <td> <%= k.text_field(:delivery_period, {placeholder: '0', class: 'form-control input_border input_field_text_align_right'})%></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
        </div>
```

but with this approach i could not get the params for the request

can anyone suggest a method

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CoffeeScript to send the data from the FORM

create the array first, and loop through the text boxes and collect data

```
arr = []

$('input#day_id').each ->
  arr.push $(this).val()
```

convert the array

```
  sample_array = JSON.stringify(arr)
```

Call the ajax

```
  $.ajax '/controller',
            type: "POST",
            data: { schedule: { days: sample_array }},
            async: true
            success:(data) ->
```

---

If you are submitting the form
create the form as follows

```
<% @class_variable.each do |f| %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'delivery_rate[]', delivery_rate %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'delivery_amount[]', delivery_amount %>
<% end %>
```